# Как изменить формат даты при запросе в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как изменить формат даты при запросе в MySQL, в базу записываю дату через `NOW()` и она имеет формат `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`, мне нужно, чтобы при получении записи дата была формата `d:m:Y H:i`.
Для этого делаю запрос, используя

```
DATE_FORMAT(): SELECT * DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM comm.
```

Но дата все равно идет в виде `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип поля какой? Должен быть `DateTime`, а так ваша функция прекрасно работает:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-07-25 18:01:02', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

Результат:

```
24/07/2018 05:03
```

Comment: тип поля datetime, но выводит без форматирования

Comment: @aSpectro а какая версия mysql?

Comment: версия mysql 5.6

Comment: @aSpectro фиг его знает) А выполните мой запрос, что вернется?

Comment: @aSpectro на 5.6 тоже все норм выполняется :<

Comment: не стал ходить вокруг да около, сделал через функцию php date()

Comment: @aSpectro мне кажется решение было где-то на поверхности ;)

Answer (score 1):

В php есть замечательная функция date: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php . Установив нужный фильтр вы получите желаемый результат.

```
date("D.m.Y",strtotime($datetime))
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую